# Add label in neo4j 1.8

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I had created a `GraphDatabaseService` and created a node.

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

org.neo4j.graphdb.Node customer=graphDb.createNode();
```

Now I require to add a label to the node to identify that the node as customer.

Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: Do you mean a `Label` as in [Neo4j labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html) or do you mean a property on the actual node? Reading on labels can also be found [here](http://neo4j.com/blog/nodes-are-people-too/)

Comment: Neo4j Labels only. How can i set it using java programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j Labels are not supported for Neo4j 1.x. They were introduced in Neo4j 2.

For more info, check out

- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html
- http://neo4j.com/blog/nodes-are-people-too/

Therefore, what you are asking is not possible without upgrading to Neo4j 2.x.

Comment: Thanks. Neo4j 2.x. is not Java 1.6 compatible. Right?

Comment: @AnoobCI, nope. It requires Java 7. But, with that being said: If you integrate with Neo4j using REST there are multiple language bindings (any language can speak REST). If you are unable to upgrade I would suggest that you run your app in Java 6 via REST API and that Neo4j runs in a separate process using Java 7. Check [this link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-requirements.html) for more info on deployment requirements.